# what is program in plsql to check whether it is prime using function and procedure

Tags: plsql

```
declare
K number;
Lnumber;
f number;
 function prime(n in number, I in number) return is flag
begin
i:=2;
flag:=1;
n:=&n;
for i in 2..n/2
loop
if mod(n,i)=0
then
flag:=0;
exit;
end if;                                                                                             
end loop;
if flag=1
then
dbms_output.put_line('prime');
else
dbms_output.put_line('not prime');
end if;
return flag;
end;
begin
k:=4;
L:=1;
f:= prime(n,i);
dbms_output.put_line(given number is ||flag);
end;
/
```

I am getting output as this I wonder what is wrong with my code:

```
Enter value for n: 4
old   9: n:=&n;
new   9: n:=4;
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06540: PL/SQL: compilation error
ORA-06553: PLS-906: Compilation is not possible
```

q2

```
SQL> DECLARE
     num  NUMBER;
  3     c    NUMBER;
  4
  5     PROCEDURE fact (x IN NUMBER, f OUT NUMBER)
  6     IS
          7  l_var  NUMBER := 1;
  8     BEGIN
  9        FOR i IN 1 .. x
 10        LOOP
 11           l_var := l_var * i;
 12        END LOOP;
 13
 14        f := l_var;
 15     END;
 16  BEGIN
 17     num := 6;
 18     fact (num, c);
 19     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (' Factorial of ' || num || ' is ' || c);
 20  END;
```

.
in this 2nd code the result is not getting displayed , not only for this even for other codes it is showing the line PL/SQL procedure successfully completed. but the results are not displaying what is wrong with it

Comment: For q2 you need to execute "set serveroutput on" before your pl/sql block - it is not unclear if you did that. For q1 ... well there is too much wrong with your code to start fixing it. I suggest you start with the absolute minimum code that runs and work from there. Writing a whole program in a language you're not familiar with is never a good idea. Please don't ask multiple questions in a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

A fixed version of q1 might be something like this (comments inline):

```
declare
    -- k number;  -- not used
    -- l number;  -- previously "lnumber;" not used anyway
    f number;

    function prime
        ( n in number )  -- "i" parameter never used
        return number  -- added return type
    is
        flag number := 1;  -- added datatype, initial value and semicolon
    begin
        -- i := 2;  -- Can't modify an IN parameter
        -- flag := 1;  -- not needed, can assign a value when declaring
        -- n    := &n;    -- Can't modify an IN parameter

        for i in 2 .. n / 2 loop
            if mod(n, i) = 0 then
                flag := 0;
                exit;
            end if;
        end loop;
        
        if flag = 1 then
            dbms_output.put_line('prime');
        else
            dbms_output.put_line('not prime');
        end if;
        
        return flag;
    end prime;  -- added closing tag for clarity
begin
    -- k := 4;  -- not used
    -- l := 1;  -- not used
    -- f := prime(n, i); -- n and i are not declared

    f := prime(123);
    
    dbms_output.put_line('prime check returns '|| f);  -- added quotes, changed "flag" to "f"
end;
```

Also I formatted the code to make it more readable. This also helps when writing code, as it keeps the structure clearly visible and makes some errors more obvious.

q2 works for me, so you probably just need to check how whatever tool you are using displays dbms_output. In some tools there is a checkbox, others require a `set server output on` command.

You can also provide a function implementation of your factorial procedure:

```
declare
    num number;
    c   number;

    procedure fact
        ( num in  number
        , f   out number )
    is
    begin
        f := 1;

        for i in 2 .. num loop
            f := f * i;
        end loop;
    end fact;


    function fact
        ( num number )
        return number
    is
        f number;
    begin
        fact(num, f);
        return f;
    end fact;

begin
    num := 6;
    fact(num, c);
    dbms_output.put_line('Factorial of ' || num || ' is ' || c);

    dbms_output.put_line('Factorial of ' || num || ' is ' || fact(num));
end;
```